# MySQL ORDER BY result from sub select as INTEGER

Tags: mysql

my ORDER BY (ORDER BY count_wall) ordered by as String, but i will order by as Integer:

```
(SELECT COUNT(wc.id) FROM weighting_contra wc WHERE wc.entry_contra_id in (1,2,3,4)) as count_wc,
(SELECT COUNT(wp.id) FROM weighting_pro wp WHERE wp.entry_pro_id in (1,2,3,4)) as count_wp,
(SELECT IFNULL(count_wc,0) + IFNULL(count_wp,0)) as count_wall
```

I have tested count_wall * 1 and ABS(count_wall) or ABS() in ORDER BY clause ...nothing help, it orders by as String.
I cant understand this, because count_wall is definitive an Integer.
Perhaps someone can help me.

I have found some: ORDER BY with CASE dont work ...here the complete, dont work, code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `proc_test_order_by`(p_order_by VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
select
t.id as topic_id, t.title as topic_title, t.alias as topic_alias, t.time_create, t.is_public,
(SELECT COUNT(ec.id) FROM entry_contra ec WHERE ec.topic_id = t.id) as count_ec,
(SELECT COUNT(ep.id) FROM entry_pro ep WHERE ep.topic_id = t.id) as count_ep,
(SELECT IFNULL(count_ec,0) + IFNULL(count_ep,0)) as count_eall,

(SELECT COUNT(wc.id) FROM weighting_contra wc WHERE wc.entry_contra_id in (SELECT ec.id FROM entry_contra ec WHERE ec.topic_id = t.id)) as count_wc,
(SELECT COUNT(wp.id) FROM weighting_pro wp WHERE wp.entry_pro_id in (SELECT ep.id FROM entry_pro ep WHERE ep.topic_id = t.id)) as count_wp,
(SELECT IFNULL(count_wc,0) + IFNULL(count_wp,0)) as count_wall
from topic t
WHERE t.is_public = 1
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY 
    CASE p_order_by
    WHEN 'topic_alias' THEN topic_alias 
    WHEN 'time_create' THEN time_create
    WHEN 'count_ec' THEN count_eall
    WHEN 'count_ep' THEN count_eall
    WHEN 'count_wc' THEN count_wall
    WHEN 'count_wp' THEN count_wall
    ELSE time_create
    END
DESC;
END
```

And now the code that work:

```
select
t.id, t.title,
(SELECT COUNT(ec.id) FROM entry_contra ec WHERE ec.topic_id = t.id) as count_ec,
(SELECT COUNT(ep.id) FROM entry_pro ep WHERE ep.topic_id = t.id) as count_ep,
(SELECT IFNULL(count_ec,0) + IFNULL(count_ep,0)) as count_eall,

(SELECT COUNT(wc.id) FROM weighting_contra wc WHERE wc.entry_contra_id in (SELECT ec.id FROM entry_contra ec WHERE ec.topic_id = t.id)) as count_wc,
(SELECT COUNT(wp.id) FROM weighting_pro wp WHERE wp.entry_pro_id in (SELECT ep.id FROM entry_pro ep WHERE ep.topic_id = t.id)) as count_wp,
(SELECT IFNULL(count_wc,0) + IFNULL(count_wp,0)) as count_wall
from topic t
WHERE t.is_public = 1
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY count_wall
DESC;
```

...can someone explain that?

Comment: My guess is that `count_wall` is defined as a string in one of the tables you are joining in, and that is being used for the `order by`.

Comment: no, there is no column `count_wall` in other tables